# using sweet alert on disabled bootstrap button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, sweetalert

Is it possible to use sweet alert on a disabled bootstrap button?

I have a button :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'deleteStaff/' . $record->userId; ?>">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" <?php  if 
(!$permission_allowed_delete == true) {?>disabled<?php } ?>>
<span class="btn-label"><i class="mdi mdi-trash-can-outline"></i></span>Delete</button>
</a>
```

The button is dynamically disabled based on user role. I want to add a sweet alert that notifies the user that they do not have permission to delete if they try clicking the disabled button.

I have tried adding sweet alert to the button by echoing the sweet alert id in the if statement. But as the button is disabled it also disables the sweet alert.

Any suggestions on how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad UI design so don't do it. Also things like that might not works the same across browser depending on how you try to work around that.

Either the control is enabled and respond to user click or the control is disabled and does not respond to user click.

If you want to tell some information to your user then write it directly on the web page next to the control or add an "Info" button next to the check box that would display the message when you click on that button.

You have to remember that users won't know that it is possible to click on a disable check box so no one will try it so you would have waste time to implement it.
Even if you need it:

> Wrap your disabled button with another element & use onClick event
> there
> For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function dcl(eve)
            {
                alert("Your Message");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div onClick="dcl(this)" style=width:18px;height:16px">
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of things here:

1. You can wrap your button with a div element and you can detect a click event on that div. It'll allow you to call sweetalert with javascript even if the button is disabled because the div itself is not disabled.
2. Instead of showing a sweetalert message, you can change the cursor of the button to a `not-allowed` one if the button is disabled (you can do that by adding a special class when you check if the user has permission to delete a staff member or not).

---

**WARNING:**
Just a tip here, don't rely on the HTML `disabled` attribute if you're doing role-based management because a user can simply remove the disabled attribute from the button and they'll be able to use the button normally.

You should always check in the backend if they have permission to do the task they are trying to do or not.

Comment: All the checking is done in the controller, this is purely for aesthetic purposes. I could remove the button entirely or make it disabled. after showing a few people they voted for the disabled button so i went for it.

Comment: @JamesC Glad to know so. I'm glad you got it all figured out :)